# eclipse ide console view information to eclipse rcp console view

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have created a eclipse rcp application where I need to add the console view.
Now what I wanted to know is, the console view in the eclipse rcp application should be able to see the log information or any `system.out.println` which is in eclipse IDE console view. That means all the information available in javacode like `system.out.println()`, log information,etc should be availble in eclipse rcp console view. I have added the console view in eclipse rcp application but no console informations are displayed. Now my question is this really possible to achieve?If yes,could any one suggest me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

To display output in the console view you need to add one or more consoles to the view using:

```
ConsolePlugin.getDefault().getConsoleManager().addConsoles(console array)
```

The console implements `IConsole` and normal extends `AbstractConsole`, you may be able to use one of predefined console classes such as `IOConsole`.

You will have to arrange that the output you want is sent to this console.